# accessing angular service in a different module from angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this service that I am trying to access but it keeps saying that the service is undefined.

```
'use strict';

var $services = angular.module('services', []);
$services.factory('userService', function(){
    return {
        loginOnServer:function(){
            console.log('enter function service');
        }
   }
});
```

Here is the controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('kp.login', ['ngRoute', 'services'])

.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', 'userService', function(sc, userService) {
        console.log("got to the controller");

     sc.login= function(sc, userService){
        console.log("call login on service");
        console.log(userService);
        userService.loginOnServer();
     }

}]);
```

userService is undefined in the controller.

Comment: Which `userService`? The one passed as a dependency, or the one passed as a parameter in the `login` method?  If you want the one that is declared in the `services` module, you should not be overriding the name in the `login` function.  Either rename the parameter or remove it if you want to reference `userService` from the outer scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a new function parameter called `userService` in your login method. simply use this line instead:

```
sc.login= function(sc){
```